# .htaccess redirect works for .html but not .php using RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to restrict access to a directory and all of its' sub-dirs and file using the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^(.*)ht-test(.*)$ - [NC,R=401,L]
</IfModule>
```

It works fine on index.html but not test.php. I have not clue what's going on. Shouldn't `^(.*)ht-test(.*)$` match anything containing it in the URL? Tested it with [this site](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) and it seems to be mathing both php and html.

I also tried using `<Directory "./ht-test"> Deny from All </Directory>` but that gives me Internal Server Error no matter what I put in.

Here're my tests:

http://deepcorelabs.com/ht-test/index.html

http://deepcorelabs.com/ht-test/test.php

Comment: @anubhava Nope, only the index.php and test.html. I just tried asdf.php which doesn't exist and it gives me a non-standard `File not found`. However, asdf.html works as expected I wonder if my apache/nginx setup somehow bypasses it...

Comment: No, only what's in the question.

Comment: Ah you have `nginx` not Apache. .htaccess rules are not fully supported in nginx

Comment: Hmmm... I was running in proxy mode and even though I just disabled it it's still saying `Server: nginx` in the response header. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, figured it out. There's a settings in Plesk for how PHP is served (under `Hosting Settings` for the domain)

I was using `FPM application served by nginx` which igonores .htaccess directives for PHP files.
[Apparently, for performance reasons](https://talk.plesk.com/threads/plesk-11-5-nginx-no-htaccess.287993/)

After changing it to 'served by Apache' it worked as expected.
[image]

For some reason I thought disabling nginx proxy mode will disable it completely as service.